# Combining Dictionary<A,B> + Dictionary<B,C> to create Dictionary<A,C>

Tags: c#, dictionary

Any cool quick ways to take two dictionaries to create a third that maps the key of the first to the value of the second in an inner-join style?

```
Dictionary<A,B> dic1 = new Dictionary<A,B> {{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3}};
Dictionary<B,C> dic2 = new Dictionary<B,C> {{b1,c1},{b2,c2},{b4,c4}};

Dictionary<A,C> dic3 = SomeFunction(dic1,dic2);
// dic3 = {{a1,c1},{a2,c2}}
```

Comment: Do you want the new dictionary to be "live"? That is, if you make dic3, and then someone changes values in dic1 and dic2, does dic3's behaviour change?

Comment: My answer below interpreted your question as essentially an inner join, but perhaps you intended a left outer join or right outer join? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Eric - my intention is for non-live usage.

Comment: @Roly - q updated to specify inner join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this to join on the inner value

```
Dictionary<int, string> first = new Dictionary<int, string> { {1, "hello"}, {2, "world"}};

Dictionary<string, bool> second = 
    new Dictionary<string, bool> { { "hello", true }, {"world", false}};

var result = (from f in first
              join s in second on f.Value equals s.Key
              select new { f.Key, s.Value }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

If you dump out result you'll see it is a Dictionary with the value `{1: true, 2: false}`

Comment: This looks legit and also quite pretty; I am not familiar enough with `join` though to know if it's efficient. Can you reassure is? +1 for prettiness at least :).

Comment: I'm not sure how it is implemented, but I would imagine that if the second dictionary is not sorted, it would run in O(m*n) time where m and n are the sizes of the left and right dictionary, respectively. But I don't think that's any different from the other solutions presented which have a for loop on the first dictionary and a where clause on the second

Comment: Dictionaries are implemented as hash tables with O(1) lookup. Join assumes that the sequences being joined are *not* fast lookup tables so it builds its own fast lookup table out of one of the sequences. So this solution is not more time-efficient than the naive solution, and does potentially create a lot of garbage during its operation.

Comment: Interesting. So is this assumption just limited to join or do other LINQ operations suffer from this assumption as well?

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
Dictionary<string, string> a, b, c;

//code to initialize the 3 dictionaries. a,b are original dictionaries and c is the new dictionary

c = ( from ak in a.Keys
    where b.ContainsKey( ak )
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>( ak, b[ ak ] ) ).ToDictionary( d => d.Key, d=> d.Value );
```

Comment: Does this work because it is comparing Keys to Keys and not Keys to values?

Comment: @Mike - i think he wanted a key of 1st to value of 2nd mapping, have edited my answer. thnx

Comment: I think the issue is the join he also wants to join value from 1 to key 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Dictionary<A,C> SomeFunction(dic1, dic2)
{
    var dic3 = new Dictionary<A,C>();
    foreach (var item in dic1)
    { 
         var item2 = dic2.Where(m=>m.Key == item.Value).FirstOrDefault(); 
         if (item2 != null) 
         {
             dic3.Add(item.Key, item2.Value);
         } 
    }
    return dic3
}
```

I believe this will work for what you want

Comment: +1 I like this one the best because it actually deals with the case where dic2 is missing keys for values in dic1.

Comment: It does that by adding `null` as the value for the corresponding key though. Not sure if that's the desired behavior.

Comment: @Domenic: Since the TS doesn't state wether he want's to include null values this seems the best.  Also I noticed this doesn't check wether there are values in dic2 that are not being added but also here, TS doesn't state.

Comment: The problem is then you can't tell the difference between a `null` that came from `dic2` or a `null` that arises because `dic2` didn't have a value for that key.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something with ToDictionary

```
dic1.Where(d1=>dic2.ContainsKey(d1.Value)).ToDictionary(d1=>d1.Key,d1=>dic2[d1.Value]);
```

Comment: Blows up if there are any Bs in dic1 that are not in dic2, -1.

Comment: OK, but now it adds `null`, which is bad because `null` is a valid value to store in a dictionary and cannot be used as a signifier for "missing value."

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dictionary<int, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        Dictionary<string, decimal> dic2 = new Dictionary<string,decimal>();

        dic1.Add(1, "one");
        dic1.Add(2, "two");
        dic1.Add(3, "three");
        dic1.Add(4, "four");
        dic1.Add(5, "five");

        dic2.Add("one",1.0m);
        dic2.Add("two", 2.0m);
        dic2.Add("three", 3.0m);
        dic2.Add("four", 4.0m);
        dic2.Add("five", 5.0m);


        Dictionary<int, decimal> result = (from d1 in dic1
                                           from d2 in dic2
                                           where d1.Value == d2.Key
                                           select new { d1.Key, d2.Value }).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key, p=>p.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IDictionary<A, C> SomeFunction<A, B, C>(IDictionary<A, B> dic1, IDictionary<B, C> dic2)
{
    var dic3 = new Dictionary<A, C>();
    foreach (var item in dic1)
    {
        var a = item.Key;
        var b = item.Value;
        if (dic2.ContainsKey(b))
        {
            var c = dic2[b];
            dic3.Add(a, c);
        }
    }

    return dic3;
}
```

Handles the case of `dic2` not containing keys corresponding to `dic1`s value without fake `null` values being stored, and IMO is pretty clear. I do like some LINQ, but I thought I'd give a procedural answer for once...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
var dict3 = dict1.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => dict2[p.Value]);
```